# Laravel ManyToMany проверить существует ли запись в сводной таблице

Tags: laravel5, many-to-many

Есть 2 модели (например Занятия Lesson и пользователи User) связь ManyToMany.
Нужно проверить существует-ли пользователь на этом занятии . Каким образом это можно осуществить?

Делаю так, но это не работает, отрабатывает ветка "не назначен"

```
$lesson = Lesson::where('theme',$request->theme)->first();

      $users = $request->users;

      foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($lesson->users()->where('user_id', $user)->exists()) { // проверка назначен ли юзер уже на это занятие
          return back()->with('warning', 'не назначен!');
        } else {
          $lesson->users()->attach($user);
        }
      }
      return back()->with('success', 'начзначен!');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Представим, что `$users = $request->users` это массив с идентификаторами `id` пользователей:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => 15
  1 => 32
  2 => 48
  3 => 59
]
```

Массив пришел на сторону сервера с заполненной формы вашего сайта, и где-то выше по коду произведена проверка входящих данных (валидация), в частности и на наличие пользователей с указанными `id` в БД.

Далее по коду, вы выполняете проверку в цикле на привязанность пользователя к занятию:

```
$lesson->users()->where('user_id', $user)->exists()
```

При отправки формы в первый раз, в БД не существует связей каждого из пользователей с конкретным занятием (Lesson). И они все благополучно "записываются на занятие":

```
$lesson->users()->attach($user);
```

Но при повторной отправке формы уже отрабатывает перенаправление (редирект) обратно на страницу с формой, которую вы заполняли, если у данного занятия (Lesson) существует хотя бы один пользователь, удовлетворяющий условию `where('user_id', $user)`:

```
return back()->with('warning', 'не назначен!');
```

При этом цикл может прерваться на первом пользователе из массива. Это и есть причина того, почему `отрабатывает ветка "не назначен"`.

---

У метода `exists()` существует один подводный камень:

```
$user = new User;

// Вернёт false.
$user->exists;

// Вернёт true. Хотя пользователя в БД не существует!!!
$user->exists();
```

Помимо метода `exists()` вы можете проверить привязку пользователя следующим образом:

```
$lesson = Lesson::with('users')
  ->where('theme', $request->theme)
  ->first();

$users = $request->users;

foreach ($users as $user) {
  if ($lesson->users->contains($user)) {
    // Пользователь записан на занятие.
  } else {
    // Пользователь НЕ записан на занятие.
  }
}
```

---

Что же касается самого кода, то его можно было бы переписать таким образом:

```
// Получаем занятие из БД, либо выдаём 404 ошибку.
$lesson = Lesson::where('theme', $request->theme)->firstOrFail();

// Вариант 1. Добавить указанных пользователей на занятие, удалив старых.
$lesson->users()->sync($request->users);

// Вариант 2. Либо добавить указанных пользователей на занятие, с сохранением уже существующих.
$lesson->users()->syncWithoutDetaching($request->users);

// Абстрактное формирование сообщения, только как пример.
$message = empty($request->users)
  ? 'Теперь на занятие никто не записан.'
  : 'Пользователи успешно записаны на занятия!';

return back()->with('success', $message);
```

Но опять же, не знаю, что происходит выше по коду, плюс не точно указана версия Laravel. Поэтому лучше обратиться к документации для вашей версии.